# Tracking pixel in ASP + get cookie value

Tags: cookies, asp-classic, cross-domain

So this is my situation:

User visits www.a.com where a cookie is set:

```
$.cookie('panelcookie', userid, {path: '/' });
```

When this user now visits www.b.com, where our tracking pixel is

```
<img src="http://www.a.com/trackpixel.asp" width=1 height=1>
```

, the pixel should write that userid to a log along with other info (the following is what I've come up with so far):

```
<% 


Const ForAppending = 8
 Const Create = true
 Dim FSO
 Dim TS
 Dim Panelcookie 
 Dim MyFileName
 Dim strLog
 Dim cMyValue 

 MyFileName = Server.MapPath("asptrack.txt")


  Set FSO = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 Set TS = FSO.OpenTextFile(MyFileName, ForAppending, Create)


 ' Store all the required information in a string Called strLog

 strLog = "<br><P><B>" & NOW() & "</B> "
 strLog = strLog & Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR") & " "
 strLog = strLog & Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_REFERER") & " "
 strLog = strLog & "User has cookie? " & Request.Cookies("panelcookie") & " " 
 strLog = strLog & Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_USER_AGENT") & "<BR>"



 ' Write current information to Log Text File.

 TS.write strLog
 TS.Writeline ""


%>
```

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: You can in fact incorporate an image on side B which in turn calls a page in site A, however... you should pass ALL information from site B inside the call. As in: <img src='http://www.a.com/trackpixel.asp?site=b&prop1=A&prop2=B so you have to construct the src attrib in javascript. Hence, you can only give back those things you are able to retrieve via javascript.

Comment: The solution of passing the unique userid along with the <img> won't work, as it is not available at www.b.com. So how do i get that information to my logfile?

Comment: That's right, but that information is available in that cookie on A, and since the pixel.asp is processed from A you've got it there. So userid from the cookie and the request from the query string.

Comment: So i've added some things to pass from B til A (siteID etc.), but the cookie value comes up empty when written to log. Maybe I'm not understanding you correctly. Should this not write the cookievalue to the log:

strLog = strLog & "User has cookie? " & Request.Cookies("panelcookie") & " "